# boost conditional not working on thread safe queue with two producers and one consumer

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, queue

I have two threads that add to a "thread safe" queue. However when the second thread attempts to "push" contents. The consumer is not notified that contents are available. The queue continues to grow but the notify_one() never notifies the conditional in the consuming method. Why is this?

```
#ifndef CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H
#define CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H

#include <queue>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

template<typename Data>
class concurrent_queue {
private:
    std::queue<Data> the_queue;
    mutable boost::mutex the_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
public:
    void push(Data const& data) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        the_queue.push(data);
        lock.unlock();
        the_condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.empty()) {
            the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
        }

        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
    }
};
#endif
```

---

This code does work in Fedora 14 using boost 1.51.0, however it does not work in boost 1.50.0 in windows 7.

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    . \
    /home/mehoggan/Devel/x86-fps/boost_1_50_0/include

LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=/home/mehoggan/Devel/x86-fps/boost_1_50_0/lib

LIBS += \
    -L/home/mehoggan/Devel/x86-fps/boost_1_50_0/lib \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_thread \
    -lz

#ifndef CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H
#define CONCURRENT_QUEUE_H

#include <queue>
#include <boost/thread.hpp> // Using boost 1.50.0

template<typename Data>
class concurrent_queue {
private:
    std::queue<Data> the_queue;
    mutable boost::mutex the_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
public:
    void push(Data const& data) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        the_queue.push(data);
        lock.unlock();
        the_condition_variable.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.empty()) {
            the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
        }

        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
    }
};
#endif

concurrent_queue<int> the_queue;

void thread1func() {
    do {
        the_queue.push(1);
    } while (true);
}

void thread2func() {
    do {
        the_queue.push(2);
    } while (true);
}

void thread3func() {
    do {
        int read;
        the_queue.wait_and_pop(read);

        std::cout << "I read from thread " << read << std::endl;
    } while (true);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    boost::thread thread1 = boost::thread(thread1func);
    boost::thread thread2 = boost::thread(thread2func);
    boost::thread thread3 = boost::thread(thread3func);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a small driver `main()` that illustrates the problem?  I'm assuming the consumer is calling one of the `wait*pop()` functions?

Comment: Sure one sec. Working on getting code together.

Comment: while the edited code is useful, a [sscce](http://sscce.org), something that has `int main()` and can be compiled with minimal effort, would be better

Comment: I already know the defined behaviour of your change requests. I would see the variable increment (++) but i would not see it decrement (--) because it is the wait_and_pop's conditional variable that is not working with two producers.

Comment: What tools and command lines are you using to build your example above? How were the Boost libraries built?I tried your program on Win7 x64 compiled with nuwen's MinGW (which includes Boost already built) and it ran fine.  My nuwen install has MinGW 4.7.2 and Boost 1.51.  The current nuwen build (9.6) has the same MinGW version but includes Boost 1.53: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: I also tried the program with VS 2010 built against Boost 1.49 libraries and had no problems with the consumer thread remaining blocked - it continued to read data posted from both threads 1 and 2.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan, Win7 x86 + VS 2010 + Boost 1.52. The code works correctly. IMHO, the `lock.unlock();` line is not necessary in the `push` method.

Comment: @megabyte1024: you're right that the `unlock()` isn't necessary, but it's not incorrect either. Releasing the lock before notifying a condition variable is intended to prevent a situation where a waiting thread is unblocked by the notify only to be immediately blocked by the mutex that the notifying thread is needlessly still holding.

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile doesn't seem to use -pthread/-mthreads. In general don't expect your code to work at all if you are not asking for the compiler to generate multi-threaded code.